# Content is not allowed in trailing section in my web.xml

Tags: java, xml, jersey

I am make a web application using jersey. But my web.xml is show error. How to solve this error.

Thanks

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

        <display-name>mdm</display-name>
        <servlet>
                <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
                <servlet-name>MdmServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
                        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                        <param-value>com.avanir.mdm.app.service.hcp, com.avanir.mdm.app.service.dcr,com.avanir.mdm.app.service.onekey,com.avanir.mdm.app.service.solr,com.avanir.mdm.app.service.user</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
                        <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>MdmServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>//error line
```

but I get the error the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed, and it is at the servlet-mapping part. I tried putting the servlet mapping inside of servlet and it got rid of the error but the webpage http://localhost:8081/WebProject01/dwr/ still wouldn't come up. The dwr.xml didn't have any errors so that looked good. Is there another way to fix the error message? Thanks for your time.

Comment: please don't consider below the xml file paragraph ....

Comment: Looks valid, just make sure there is nothing after the `</web-app>` at the end.